# EasyUI Datagrid with two identical fields and diffrent formatter

Tags: javascript, jquery-easyui

I have an EasyUI Datagrid with two identical fields like this :

```html
<th data-options="field:'listprice',width:80,align:'right',formatter:formatPrice">List Price</th>

<th data-options="field:'listprice',width:80,align:'right',formatter:formatPriceToWords">List Price</th>
```

and I have 2 functions for formatting price value but for these columns, just the formatter of the first column is applying.
I have a jsfiddlethat shows exactly the problem and here is the link :

> http://jsfiddle.net/pouya_devil/vrbjudpz/2/

if you comment the first column with the **listprice** field then the second formatter Function will apply. I want to know how can implement the grid with 2 columns identical field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both columns are referencing to the same `field`. Unfortunatly the [docs](https://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/index.php) are not clear about such a situation, but this seems to be an issue.

To solve this you could introduce another row-element in your 'griddata' which duplicates the listprice.

I've forked your fiddle to clearify this: http://jsfiddle.net/zwif_/ncjperwm/

Comment: yes I know that but it is not really the best solution I'm looking for a way to not duplicating my columns because I get this data from API and I cannot change that API

Comment: I searched a lot and it seems there is no other way so I am going to mark your answer for others to know thanks